# MongoDB - Aggregate (join two collection) and return separate Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections.

I need to join them and return Array of both the collections fields. As I understand, I should use aggregate features. I try to find examples, but can't find the right for my case.

It is not easy for me, I’m new at this, and I couldn’t win against this MongoDB query.

Does anyone have any ideas?

document1 -  "ParentDocument":

```
[
{
  "code": "OF_Code",
  "version": "1",
  "createdBy": "abc",
  "attributes": {
    "associatedProducts": [
      {
        "bundleProducts": [
          {
            "products": [
              {
                "key": "REF_123"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "code": "OF_Code2",
  "version": "1",
  "createdBy": "abc",
  "attributes": {
    "associatedProducts": [
      {
        "bundleProducts": [
          {
            "products": [
              {
                "key": "REF_123"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "code": "OF_Code3",
  "version": "1",
  "createdBy": "abc",
  "attributes": {
    "associatedProducts": [
      {
        "bundleProducts": [
          {
            "products": [
              {
                "key": "REF_456"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

document2- "ReferencedDocument":

```
[
{
    "code": "REF_123",
    "status": "live"
},
{
     "code": "REF_456",
    "status": "live"
},
{
    "code": "REF_789",
    "status": "live"
}
]
```

The result that I want:

Sample 1 -  When `OF_Code` and `OF_Code2` has to be returned , the reference list should only
have matching Reference so it will have only 1 (`REF_123`)

```
{
"Parent": [
    {
        "code": "OF_Code"
    },
    {
        "code": "OF_Code2"
    },
],
"Reference": [
    {
        "code": "REF_123",
        "status": "live"
    }
]
}
```

Sample 2 - When `OF_Code` and `OF_Code2`  has to be returned , the reference list should
have matching Reference so it will have 2

```
{
"Parent": [
    {
        "code": "OF_Code"
    },
    {
        "code": "OF_Code3"
    },
],
"Reference": [
    {
        "code": "REF_123",
        "status": "live"
    },
    {
        "code": "REF_789",
        "status": "live"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but is this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LwvCCsaMGX5) close to what you are looking for?

Comment: @rickhg12hs - I tried using Group but I was using facet to query set of data based on 
limit and count.  Can we still use facet along with $group ?   {
            "$facet": {
                "Parent": [
                    {
                        "$skip": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "$limit": 50
                    }
                ],
                "pagination": [
                    {
                        "$count": "count"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

Comment: When you try it, does it do what you want?

Comment: @rickhg12hs -  https://mongoplayground.net/p/dS9Tokhqdqf
I updated the same with facet , But the Reference is coming inside Reference Object due to group.

Comment: Think this is what you looking for? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BA9neoAfdk2)

Comment: @YongShun - One Issue, In the example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/gxg-ZFKhv0B,   only REF_123 should be retuned as we are returning only its parent OF_Code,  Can it be achieved ?